# DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet error 2391 or better way to read excel

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to read multiple excel files into a table. I'm getting Run-Time error 2391: Field F10 does not exist. The line in question:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "MechanicalData", rst.Fields("Filelist"), True
```

I've already figured out that I'm getting the error because of a cell or multiple cells after all my data. Access seems to think that these blank spaces contain data. If I go into the excel file first and delete trailing columns at random, the above works fine. This isn't practical, though. I can't do that for hundreds or thousands of tables.

I'm not too familiar with handling errors. Is there a way to exclude trying to import the columns that cause the error?

Alternatively, is there a completely different function that isn't as clunky as TransferSpreadSheet?

Answer (score 0):

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet has a range argument that you can specify to tell it what cells in Excel to import. If you specify the range, it will ignore everything outside of that range.

Answer (score 0):

I found a strange fix to the Error 2391 for my spreadsheets.  It appears that the range of cells recognized by this method is contained in the left-most spreadsheet or tab in the Excel workbook. Even if you've defined the range of cells to be from a specific tab, the transfer method will ignore the tab name and take the cell range from the left-most tab.  This was also happening when the left-most tab was hidden.  So, I incorporated into the Excel VBA some code that ensured that the tab from which I wanted to transfer cells was first from left.  That plus the headers of the cell range matching the headers in the ACCESS table enabled the transfer method to work.  Hope this helps.

Comment: This is only a partial answer. Can you share the code that you used to make sure the sheet was moved to the left?

Comment: Worksheets("Upload to ACCESS").Move Before:=Worksheets(1)

Comment: That  one-line statement should work for visible tabs, though if there are  any left-most hidden tabs you'll have to unhide them first.